# How can I get Visual Studio Typescript 1.7 intellisense to work with nodejs libraries (angular2, rxjs)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular, intellisense

[SOLVED]
I logged a [bug against TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6625#issuecomment-175162891) and the fix should be rolled up into the next VS plugin release.  Essentially you can get intellisense to work if you specify your module resolution to be "NodeJs".  However the compiler doesn't like this because it expects it to be "node".  It looks like the fix they're making is to make everything work by specifying "Node".

---

I'm trying to build an Angular2 project with msbuild because I want to use ASP.Net Web API as my back-end.  The code compiles and runs fine, but my editor (SublimeText 3 or Visual Studio 2015) doesn't like the way I import the Angular2 libraries:

boot.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';  // error: cannot find module
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent, []);
```

If I run the same example ([Angular2 Hero Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)) using the TypeScript compiler directly with a tsconfig.json and node lite-server as documented, then SublimeText3 works and can recognize this syntax just fine.  However once I switch to msbuild, I get this intellisense error for some reason.  Here's other pieces of my project which I think are relevant:

Folder structure:

```
\
  - index.html
  - package.json
  \app
      - boot.ts
      - app.component.ts
  \node_modules
      \angular2
          \platform
              - browser.js
              - browser.d.ts
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-webapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.7.3" 
  }
}
```

TypeScript compiler section from csproj file (most of this was copied from the [Angular2 Hero tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) tsconfig file, but some of these were set by VS automatically):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
  <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
  <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
  <TypeScriptModuleKind>System</TypeScriptModuleKind>
  <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
  <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
  <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>true</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
  <TypeScriptModuleResolution>node</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
  <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>true</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've also tried changing the way I reference the Angular2 libraries like below since it matches the actual physical path of the browser script, but unfortunately the generated file doesn't add the ".js" extension to the generated dependency list for some reason.  This means that the browser will request the file "browser" instead of "browser.js".

This breaks the runtime:

```
import {bootstrap} from '../node_modules/angular2/platform/browser';
```

I'm actually not sure how the system is supposed to know how to resolve the 'angular2/platform/browser' syntax, but it seems to work if I don't use msbuild.  And given the fact that this code compiles and runs properly, it seems like it should work in my editor as well.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Webstorm EAP does that out of the box, and its free because its a pre-release version -> https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP

Comment: Thanks.  I'm actually only using Visual Studio because I want to be able to debug my ASP.Net Web API project locally.  I also want to point out that this appears to be build-specific and not editor specific since I run into this problem with SublimeText which normally works if I don't use msbuild.  I've updated the question to reflect that information.

Answer (score 1):

As far as project property group is set to

```
<TypeScriptModuleResolution>NodeJs</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
```

there is a workaround is to modify **Microsoft.Typescript.targets**.
It makes compiler to work:

```
<TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptModuleResolution)' != ''">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --moduleResolution $(TypeScriptModuleResolution)</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
```

hardcoded as

```
<TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptModuleResolution)' != '' and '$(TypeScriptModuleResolution)' != 'NodeJs'">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --moduleResolution $(TypeScriptModuleResolution)</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
<TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptModuleResolution)' == 'NodeJs'">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --moduleResolution node</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
```

**PS make sure to take a backup of Microsoft.Typescript.targets**

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  It looks like that would probably work as a short term solution, but I don't think I'm going to use it because it would require modifying a global targets file.  Since I'm going to be publishing this to a hosted service, I won't have access to that file.  For now I'll probably just use Sublime with a tsconfig file and wait for an update to the TS plugin for VS.  I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 0):

This does appear to be a bug in typescript tooling as @AndrewSorokin describes, but instead of editing `Microsoft.Typescript.targets`, you can override the incorrect code in your project file.  Add the following lines to the end of your project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- ... -->
  <!-- Set the Module Resolution mode to be NodeJs as required by intellisense -->
  <!-- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939261/how-can-i-get-visual-studio-typescript-1-7-intellisense-to-work-with-nodejs-libr -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <TypeScriptModuleResolution>NodeJs</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <TypeScriptModuleResolution>NodeJs</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- ... -->
  <!-- Override the moduleResolution parameter to tsc to overcome a bug in intellisense -->
  <!-- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939261/how-can-i-get-visual-studio-typescript-1-7-intellisense-to-work-with-nodejs-libr -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CompileTypeScriptDependsOn>
      SpoofTypeScriptModuleResolution;
      $(CompileTypeScriptDependsOn)
    </CompileTypeScriptDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="SpoofTypeScriptModuleResolution">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations.Replace('--moduleResolution NodeJs', '--moduleResolution node'))</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="Options: $(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```